# Copying text from one EditText box to another in the same Activity on the fly, character-by-character

Tags: android, android-edittext, listeners

I am building an application to convert Latitude and Longitudes
between various formats.  My layout is complete but my current
challenge is this:

For the Degree values, as the user enters a value in EditText1, I want
it to replicate in EditText2 as they are typing, real-time, character
for character.  I have beat myself up trying OnTouchListener,
onKeyboardActionListener, etc.

Later, I will perform calculations on the Minutes, Seconds, and
decimal portions as they are typed in.  Since the Degree field does
not require calculations I am just trying to replicate the users value
across multiple EditText boxes for now.

SUMMARY:
Capture the characters in EditText1 as they are typed
Place EditText1 captured characters into EditText2 on the fly.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Mike Murphy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested, but I found addTextChangedListener():

```
EditText firstEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.firstEditText);
firstEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s){
        String c = s.toString(); // read Content
        ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.secondEditText)).setText(c); // copy to #2
    }
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after){ }
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count){ }
});
```

http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/eba1a2ea7d3a2828?fwc=1

Comment: Thank you so much!!!  This did the trick.  I was trying to do it by implementing TextWatch in the Activity and just couldn't get it to work right.

Comment: You can accept the answer if it worked for you ;) so that the topic is 'closed'.