# how to get letter entered instantly in android?

Tags: android

I have EditText view in android .. i want when the enters a letter the application get the letter ..

that mean the need to have a listener or event handler to get each letter is entered

hope my question is clear

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText01);

        et.addTextChangedListener( new TextWatcher()
        {
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {

                try
                {
                    char currentChar = arg0.charAt(arg1); // currently typed character
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    // error
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                    int arg3) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: While try/catch also works, using an if statement `(s.length() > start)` will prevent the statement from crashing when using backspace

Answer (score 4):

You can use the method `TextView.addTextChangedListener(TextWatcher watcher)`

TextWatcher provides 3 nice methods :

```
public abstract void afterTextChanged (Editable s)

public abstract void beforeTextChanged (CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after)

public abstract void onTextChanged (CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
```

[Here the doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#addTextChangedListener%28android.text.TextWatcher%29)

Answer (score 1):

A much simpler approach would be to just override `onKeyDown()` like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) 
{
    switch (keyCode) {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_Q:
            // Do your thing here. 
            break;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the "setOnKeyListener" method in EditText.

Comment: IMHO Not really useful with the virtual keyboard

Answer (score 0):

analog to [Copying text from one EditText box to another in the same Activity on the fly, character-by-character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4611388/copying-text-from-one-edittext-box-to-another-in-the-same-activity-on-the-fly-ch)

Answer (score 0):

The Answer by Vikas almost worked for me, but not quite. Here's what i did to get the actual character typed, as it is typed:

```
EditText et = ...;
et.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) { }

    @Override public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) { }

    @Override public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        if (s.length() > start + count) {
            char c = s.charAt(start + count);
            // do something ...
        }
    }
});
```